# Ubuntu 14 + Nginx + PHPMyAdmin : how can I restrict access by IP address?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, phpmyadmin

I've tried googling but can't seem to find an answer for Nginx. How can I restrict access to PHPMyAdmin by IP address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. I just had to edit my default file like this:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

Then edit the file like this:

```
location /phpmyadmin {
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny  all;
}
```

Then I restarted to apply settings.

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Comment: What about /phpmyadmin/index.php?

Comment: As @TimMiller mentions, this won't secure /phpmyadmin/index.php since the *.php location directive will receive the request. This can be solved by using a nested location, which means some duplication of the fastcgi configuration lines. See: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/

Comment: See also this question and answer to a similar: https://serverfault.com/questions/868776/wordpress-wp-login-php-page-restriction-by-ip-in-nginx

Comment: As @TimMiller and @jeffmcneill mentioned it, I ran into this issue (securing with htpasswd). Many tutorial just propose to secure the /phpmyadmin location. But it's clearly not enough. You can still access `index.php` or even `server_privileges.php`. It need a regex sublocation (into .php location) matching `~ phpmyadmin`, and duplicate `fastcgi` config into it to really protect it.

Answer (score 0):

```
geo $admin { 
    default 0; 127.0.0.1 1; 
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    location ~ (/phpmyadmin/) {
        if ($admin = 0) { 
            return 404; 
        }
        ## fastcgi parameters ##
    }
    ## fastcgi parameters ##
}
```

Note that the second location is nested and necessary to block the /phpmyadmin/index.php script from being executed.

The geo block sets the value of $admin based on IP address.